# Python pyspark columns count

Tags: python, dataframe, pyspark, count

I have a dataset like this :

| Zone 1 | Zone 2 |
| --- | --- |
| A | A |
| A | B |
| B | A |
| A | B |
| B | B |

And I want this :

| Category | Zone | count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | Zone1 | 3 |
| B | Zone1 | 2 |
| A | Zone2 | 2 |
| B | Zone2 | 3 |

I tried with a group by Zone1 & Zone2 but it dont returns the good result
If someone can help me

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Stack the dataframe then do a `groupby` + `count`

```
expr = "stack(2, 'Zone 1', `Zone 1`, 'Zone 2', `Zone 2`) as (zone, category)"
result = df.selectExpr(expr).groupBy('category', 'zone').count()
```

Result

```
+--------+------+-----+
|category|  zone|count|
+--------+------+-----+
|       A|Zone 1|    3|
|       A|Zone 2|    2|
|       B|Zone 2|    3|
|       B|Zone 1|    2|
+--------+------+-----+
```